# SetText is Deprecated

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

Hi I am working out Xcode and Obj-C and I am getting this warning:

> Deprecations: 'setText:' is deprecated

I am wondering what the new method is

This is my code:

```
[cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am cell %d", indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Please, use the search box before asking questions :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089676/alternative-to-deprecated-uitableviewcell-settext/1089683#1089683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setText is indeed deprecated. Use textLabel setText instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am cell %d", indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought is was like that.

Answer (score 3):

When you get a deprecated warning, just alt+click on the method or property that triggered it and you will get basic info about it from documentation inside a popover view, including a property or method you should use instead.