# Can not display a string in a label or text field

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uilabel, xcode5

As an iOS programming newbie I have a probably very easy question.

I have [an iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/oauthFacebook), which fetches Facebook user data (the id, name, gender, city).

The data is printed out using `NSLog` just fine:

```
id: 597287941
first_name: Alexander
last_name: Farber
gender: male
city: Bochum, Germany
```

However I can not get the data to display in my UI:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

I have tried to use `UITextField` and `UILabel`.

And I have tried using

```
[[self userId] setText:dict[@"id"]];
```

and

```
[_firstName setText:dict[@"first_name"]];
```

And I have connected the IBOutlets [just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZXd3.png) (I think):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Below is my [DetailViewController.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthFacebook/oauthFacebook/DetailViewController.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dict;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userId;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *city;

@end
```

And the problematic part of the [DetailViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthFacebook/oauthFacebook/DetailViewController.m):

```
- (void)setDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSLog(@"id: %@", dict[@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"first_name: %@", dict[@"first_name"]);
    NSLog(@"last_name: %@", dict[@"last_name"]);
    NSLog(@"gender: %@", dict[@"gender"]);
    NSLog(@"city: %@", dict[@"location"][@"name"]);

    [[self userId] setText:dict[@"id"]];
    [_firstName setText:dict[@"first_name"]];
    [_lastName setText:dict[@"last_name"]];
    [_gender setText:dict[@"gender"]];
    [_city setText:dict[@"location"][@"name"]];
}
```

Comment: how about trying : userId.text = dict[@"id"];

Comment: Where are you calling the setDict method from?

Comment: @danielM I call `setDict` from `prepareForsegue`: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthFacebook/oauthFacebook/ViewController.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the views before the labels are initialized. Still call `setDict` in the `prepareForSegue` method to pass the information in but move the `setText` calls into the `viewDidLoad` method of the new view controller. That will update the labels after the views are initialized.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much. I will update my code @ GitHub

Answer (score 1):

@DanielM above is correct, but here's what he is trying to say.  The setDict method is getting called on the segue.  That's fine, but it's only job is to keep the values until the view is prepared...

Here is **the complete** implementation of DetailViewController:

```
// DetailViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

// this must save the values from Facebook until the VC is ready to use them
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dict;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userId;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *city;

@end


@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

// this is the key:  you cannot set the state of your views before they have
// been created.
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[self userId] setText:dict[@"id"]];
    [_firstName setText:dict[@"first_name"]];
    [_lastName setText:dict[@"last_name"]];
    [_gender setText:dict[@"gender"]];
    [_city setText:dict[@"location"][@"name"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/* don't implement this.  it's called too early to make a difference 
- (void)setDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSLog(@"id: %@", dict[@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"first_name: %@", dict[@"first_name"]);
    NSLog(@"last_name: %@", dict[@"last_name"]);
    NSLog(@"gender: %@", dict[@"gender"]);
    NSLog(@"city: %@", dict[@"location"][@"name"]);

    NSString *avatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:kAvatar, dict[@"id"]];
    NSLog(@"avatar: %@", avatar);

    [[self userId] setText:dict[@"id"]];
    [_firstName setText:dict[@"first_name"]];
    [_lastName setText:dict[@"last_name"]];
    [_gender setText:dict[@"gender"]];
    [_city setText:dict[@"location"][@"name"]];
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Thanks +1. What's the better place here for setting the labels - `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? After Daniel has answered, I've tried the former and it works too: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthFacebook/oauthFacebook/DetailViewController.m

Comment: Either is okay.  As long as it's after [super viewDidLoad];  the difference is that if the VC stays around and is presented again, say before one pushed on top of it is popped, the viewWillAppear will fire again.  This can sometimes be desirable, if for example, you expect the dict values to change while it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think setText is deprecated [SetText is Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220689/settext-is-deprecated). I think you can use text attribute of the label directly.

```
firstName.text = dict[@"first_name"];
```

Comment: I've tried `_userId.text = dict[@"id"];` and unfortunately it hasn't helped.

Comment: I think it depends on where you do this. I mean to say that this needs to be done after the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler doesn't know what kind of class it is. Can you test with a explicit cast like the example below?

```
- (void)setDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSLog(@"id: %@", dict[@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"first_name: %@", dict[@"first_name"]);
    NSLog(@"last_name: %@", dict[@"last_name"]);
    NSLog(@"gender: %@", dict[@"gender"]);
    NSLog(@"city: %@", dict[@"location"][@"name"]);

    [[self userId] setText:dict[@"id"]];
    [_firstName setText:(NSString *)dict[@"first_name"]];
    [_lastName setText:(NSString *)dict[@"last_name"]];
    [_gender setText:(NSString *)dict[@"gender"]];
    [_city setText:(NSString *)dict[@"location"][@"name"]];
}
```

Comment: Compiler does know what kind of class it is.  But it's a VC that cannot configure it's view until the view is loaded.